# Is it possible for jQuery to change the types (div, a, ul, li, etc.) of an HTML element?

Tags: jquery

For example, is it possible to change

```
<ul class="some-class-name another-class-name" id="to-be-changed">text</ul>
```

into

```
<a class="some-class-name another-class-name" id="to-be-changed">text</a>
```

?

Comment: The type of an element cannot be changed. However a *new* element of a different type can be created and swapped in either a DOM replacement (and move any children) or through text manipulation of raw [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML): “Setting the value of outerHTML replaces the element and all of its descendants with a new DOM tree constructed by parsing the specified htmlString.”

Comment: Thank you for answering and sorry for the late reply. I have found a way other than changing types to solve the initial problem.